# Order by name - cyrillic letters

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, cyrillic

I have a method which returns street names from a stored procedure, something like so

```
public List<NameUlici> GetAllNameUlici()
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringManager.GetConnectionManager()))
            {
                var model = con.Query<NameUlici>("GetNameUlici", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
                return model;
            }
        }
```

This is the stored procedure, it simply returns street names

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNameUlici]
    
AS
    SELECT name,ime_1251
    FROM ULICI_KARPOS
    RETURN
```

and back to the controller I go

```
public ActionResult GetAllStreets()
        {
            var result = dataRepo.GetAllNameUlici();
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Then I populate a dropdown with those values. The values I get are in cyrillic so I am not sure how to order them by name, like A - Z.
At the moment, I have something like this

```
$.getJSON(url, function (streets) {
            $("#streetNameID").append('<option></option>');
            $.each(streets, function (index, value) {
                $("#streetNameID").append('<option value="' + value.ime_1251 + '">' + value.ime_1251 + '</option>');
            });
        });
```

but the dropdown values are all over the place - unsorted, descending & ascending at the same time. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite terrible how you are "composing" the `<option>`. If there is a `"` or a `<` inside `ime_1251` everything will break...

```
$("#streetNameID").append(new Option(value.ime_1251, value.ime_1251));
```

Still. Your problem seems to be C#-side... and in all your C# code there is something I don't see: an ordering. Considering you are using a Stored Procedure, you could order the data inside the SP:

```
SELECT name,ime_1251
FROM ULICI_KARPOS
ORDER BY ime_1251
RETURN
```

Or you can order the data C#-side:

```
var model = con.Query<NameUlici>("GetNameUlici", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
    .OrderBy(x => x.ime_1251)
    .ToList();
```